# How do you name your releases?

Tags: java, svn, architecture, release

I am trying to set the standards and process for my product. I plan to use Subversion and tag releases. However, I am not sure how I should go about naming my release.

For instance, MyProduct-1.0-TESTING.jar? MyProduct-1.0.-QA.jar ? What will it be when it goes to different environments such as Integration, QA and Prod? How do you do it with your software?

Comment: Testing, QA, prod... That's so boring! I prefer [flashy names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames) - Sparta, Frosting, Detroit, Neptune, Impala, Harmony :):):)

Comment: MS and its fancy code names.. How about people like us who develop stable, die-but-without-a-blue-screen software? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the name schema of the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/):

```
tags/projectname-version
```

**Edit:**

How I do it:

1. develop new feature
2. build as `foo-version-SNAPSHOT.jar`
3. test this, using the latest snapshot
4. if the new feature is ready for QA, use `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:release` to:

   1. create `foo-version.jar` and deploy it to to our Maven repository
   2. bump the version in `pom.xml` to the next higer value: `1.0.1` becomdes `1.0.2-SNAPSHOT`
   3. create a SVN tag `tags/foo-version`
5. tell QA and the release manager that `foo-version.jar` is ready for testing and can be fetched from the Maven repository

Comment: so, environment name will not be part of the release that you test/send to qa?

Comment: Why should this be part of the name? I test `SNAPSHOT` versions. QA tests release versions without `-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: So.. how do you do it? Do you tag your release as 'MyProduct-1.0-Snapshot.jar'? How does a release manager know what version to promote to QA with out any naming?

Comment: nevermind, I think I got what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I always use Local (my machine)
Dev, - development
UAT  - User aceptance testing
and Prod.

The reason for local ias between release I canplay aroung and fix things locally test them then put it on the dev environment and make sure everything is tickity boo, before it moves on to UAT for the proper testing to occur.